# normalizing a matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, normalization

What does `np.linalg.norm(x, axis = 1, keepdims=True)` return?

I have a matrix `np.array([[3.0,4.0],[1, 2]])` . I am trying to normalize each row of the matrix . The answer should be `np.array([[0.6,0.8],[0.4472136,0.89442719]])` but I am not able to understand what the code does to get the answer.

Here is the code:

```
x  = np.array([[3.0,4.0],[1, 2]])
norms = np.linalg.norm(x, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
x /= norms
```

This code should give the normalized x but I don't understand what `np.linalg.norm()` is returning here.

Comment: Gives the L2 norm and keeps the number of dimensions intact, i.e. the dimension that is reduced is kept as a singleton dim (axis of length=1).

Comment: If your question can be answered by a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=numpy+linalg+norm), you have not put in the minimum effort you're required to perform before asking a question here.

Comment: No where does it mention L2 norm in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html. Numpy doesn't mention Euclidean norm anywhere in the docs. @user2357112

Comment: Under Notes : `None Frobenius norm 2-norm`. If you google for `Frobenius norm` or `2 norm`, you would have it.

Comment: @PranayAryal: See the table under `Notes`, which says that the vector norm calculated for `ord=None` is a 2-norm.

Comment: I have answered the question below so that someone can understand in one google search @user2357112

Answer (score 4):

`np.linalg.norm(x, axis = 1, keepdims=True)` is doing this in every row (for x):

`np.sqrt(3**2 + 4**2)` for row 1 of x which gives 5

`np.sqrt(1**2 + 2**2)` for row 2 of x which gives 2.23

This vector `[5, 2.23]` is then the `norms` variable

All values in x are then divided by this `norms` variable which should give you `np.array([[0.6,0.8],[0.4472136,0.89442719]])`. I hope this helps

Please also see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html

Comment: You asked and answered the question in 7 mins. You should search well your questions before asking here!

Comment: @RenS the question was asked and answered so that it helps other people.